# Jquery Bounce Effect not working with classes applied to anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I need some serious help. Im trying to create a bounce effect, however it doesnt work on anchor text classes/divs.

this is the code I used: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-bounce-effect-bounce-html-js/

Its based off a very simple and short tutorial. The issue now is that I cant make the javascript code target a class or div that is inside a anchor / link.

How do I actually solve this? the code is in the website above and the section of code that im trying to bounce is highlighted in bold:

```
                <div id="jplayer">
    </div>
    <div class="jp-audio">
      <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
            <li><a href="#" **class="jp-play"**></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-prev"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-next"></a></li>
            <li><a href="audio_samples.php" class="jp-more-songs">Listen to more Audio Samples</a></li>
        </ul>
          <div class="jp-progress">
            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-title"></div>
        </div>
```

Edit: I think this issue is impossible to solve. I wondering if this is even solvable now. The background is removed everytime the class bounces.

Comment: Here the Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/96kXt/25/
It actually bounces it seems but any background image or color is gone meanwhile it does...Cant anybody fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't prevented the default behavior of the link, such that it's refreshing the page before you see the bounce effect.

I'd try the following:

```
$('#jp_interface_1 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
});
```

**Note** if you have other events that are bound to the anchor tag in question, remove the e.stopPropagation(); call.

**edit**
I just noticed you mentioned the same problem for divs. Are you wrapping your code in jQuery's document.ready handler?

```
$(function() {
    $('#jp_interface_1 a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: I will give it a try! Thank you so much for your quick response. I will let you know right away if it worked

Comment: in jQuery.jplayer.settings.js, you have the following:

    $(".jp-prev,.jp-next")
  .click( function() { 
   jPlay($(this).is('.jp-next')?'next':'prev')
   return false;
  })

if you're setting the bounce effect in a separate file, the return false line here will potentially prevent the other event from execution.

Comment: So you recommend I better leave the bounce effect?

Answer (score 0):

*The issue now is that I cant make the javascript code target a class or div that is inside a anchor / link.*

```
 <div class="div1">  div text
  <a class="ancClass" href="#">Back</a>  
  </div>
```

... This will help you to find

```
 $('.div1 a.ancClass');
```

viceversa

**EDIT :**
I dont understand what you are trying to achieve is this what you are trying ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
 $('.jp-interface a.jp-next').click(function(e) {         
    $('.jp-more-songs').effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#jp_interface_1 .jp-more-songs').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96kXt/23/

Comment: Your code works but not for the class im trying to bounce: http://jsfiddle.net/96kXt/25/

Comment: I tried a, tried a.jp-next ,everything. Everytime I click on it the background is gone until it finishes bouncing. With other words the person wont be able to see the bounce

Comment: U'mm I' haven't noted your previous comment " It actually bounces it seems but any background image or color is gone meanwhile it does." sorry ....